# High pitch noise when 3.5 jack connected on iMac 27" 2019 while using Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, imac

I need some help. Suddenly, all sounds transformed into high pitch noise when i use headphones with 3.5mm jack. I've tried reinstall of a drivers and even reinstall of the Windows. Nothhing helped. On macOS everything is fine.

iMac 27" 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the Windows 11 Preview instead of Windows 10 and it's helped.